# Programmatically selecting the item in a Combo Box PySimpleGui

Tags: python

I have created a Combo box that lists the available Serial Ports on my system using the following lines:

```py
com_ports = serial_ports()
sg.Combo(com_ports, size=(10, 1), key='Open_Port')
```

Where `serial_ports()` is a py routine I found that works platform independent.
This all works as expected EXCEPT it comes up with a blank entry when run and I have to select the Com port I want (usually only one anyway).  Am I doing something wrong, I would have thought it would select the first item in the list.  There seems to be no easy way to force it to select the first item on the list.

Various attempts at forcing it produced assorted errors.  Update can't be called before a read or a Finalize, neither of which I could add.  I did print `com_ports` and I get the items expected and if I do select a com port, then I cannot after select nothing, so there it not an empty entry at the top of the list.  It just seems to be blank.  I can't specify the default since I don't know what it is.

```py
# Set the Com Port Selection
#if com_ports:
#    window['Open_Port'].read()
#    window['Open_Port'].update(set_to_index=0)
```

`.update` COULD be called in response to an event after a read, but I need to set it before any events occur when it is first displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To update the GUI, it should after GUI finalized, you can use

- Option `finalize=True` in `Window`
- method `window.finalize()`
- method `window.read()`

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

com_ports = [f'Port {i}' for i in (1, 2, 3)]

layout = [[sg.Combo(com_ports, size=(10, 5), key='-COMBO-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
if com_ports:
    window['-COMBO-'].update(set_to_index=0)
window.read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!  That works, that was very useful and fast.  I did not need the window.read(close=True) line.  What does that do exactly?

Comment: For `window.read(close=True)`, it will wait any event from GUI and then close the window.

Comment: If you have the list of choices available in your layout, you can use the `defaulit_value` parameter.  `layout = [[sg.Combo(com_ports, default_value=com_ports[0] if len(com_ports) else None, size=(10, 5), key='-COMBO-')]]`